# Odd use case for SQL Pivot Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I'm not sold that a SQL Pivot table is the answer to my problem but it is my best guess solution right now.  I'm not a SQL expert, so all of my options have just been through research

A piece of software I use spits out a report into Microsoft SQL daily that has about 35,000 rows of data in it all of those rows contain different pieces of statistics about applications I use.  Now While I do not need each Row's data point there are maybe 110 Rows of Data I need that information from.

The Columns I currently get are in the attached screenshot

1. Data_id
2. report_id
3. data_point_group_key
4. data_point
5. data_point_value

Current Sample:

`+---------+-----------+----------------------+------------+-----------------+
| Data_id | report_id | data_point_group_key | data_point | data_point_value|
+---------+-----------+----------------------+------------+-----------------+
| 1       | 517       | 111                  | Table Name | Work_state      |
+---------+-----------+----------------------+------------+-----------------+
| 2       | 517       | 111                  | # Rows     | 3               |
+---------+-----------+----------------------+------------+-----------------+
| 3       | 517       | 111                  | Size       | 100             |
+---------+-----------+----------------------+------------+-----------------+
| 4       | 517       | 222                  | Mode Name  | New App         |
+---------+-----------+----------------------+------------+-----------------+
| 5       | 517       | 333                  | Total Size | 5000000         |
+---------+-----------+----------------------+------------+-----------------+
| 6       | 517       | 444                  | Table Name | Offline Users   |
+---------+-----------+----------------------+------------+-----------------+
| 7       | 517       | 444                  | # Rows     | 100             |
+---------+-----------+----------------------+------------+-----------------+
| 8       | 517       | 444                  | Size       | 500             |
+---------+-----------+----------------------+------------+-----------------+
| 9       | 517       | 555                  | URI        | C:\File1        |
+---------+-----------+----------------------+------------+-----------------+`

- data_id is a incremental number that is different for each row
- reprot_id is what separates today's reports from yesterdays
- data_point_group_key is a grouping of information if the rows are all related to top field in the group number.
- data_point is the Type of data being displayed
- data_point_value is the information needed for the data_point

I have to move all of this data into a secondary tool that needs to ingest the data through a column approach and not in rows.

I have no problem typing out the 110 rows to begin with but I am trying to automate this process over the long haul.

I started with this SQL command to convert, it does not fully work but it is a 
start I think

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT [data_id],
       [report_id],
       [data_point],
       [data_point_value]
FROM dbo.tblReportData
)  AS SourceTable PIVOT(MAX([report_id]) FOR [data_point_value] IN([Default Time Zone],
                   [Version],
                   [File Path],
                   [# of Active Data Feeds],
                   [Log Path])) AS PivotTable;
```

Desired Output

`+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----+-----------+--------------+-------+
| Data_id | report_id | Table Name | # of Rows | Size| Mode Name | Total Size   | URI   |
+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----+-----------+--------------+-------+
| 1       | 517       |  Work State|   3       | 100 |   NULL    |   NULL       | NULL  |
+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----+-----------+--------------+-------+
| 2       | 517       |  NULL      |   NULL    | NULL|   New App |   NULL       | NULL  |
+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----+-----------+--------------+-------+
| 3       | 517       |  NULL      |   NULL    | NULL|   NULL    |   500000     | NULL  |
+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----+-----------+--------------+-------+
| 4       | 517       |Offline user|   100     | 500 |   NULL    |   NULL       | NULL  |
+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----+-----------+--------------+-------+
| 5       | 517       |  NULL      |   NULL    | NULL|   NULL    |   NULL       |C:\File|
+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----+-----------+--------------+-------+`

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Rather than an image, provide it as text: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `CASE WHEN` with `MAX` *Aggregate function* to make your Pivot table.

**TestDLL**

```
CREATE TABLE tblReportData(
   Data_id INT,
   report_id INT,
   data_point_group_key INT,
   data_point VARCHAR(50),
   data_point_value VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO tblReportData VALUES ( 1,517 , 111 ,'Table Name','Work_state');
INSERT INTO tblReportData VALUES ( 2,517 , 111 ,'# Rows','3');
INSERT INTO tblReportData VALUES ( 3,517 , 111 ,'Size','100');
INSERT INTO tblReportData VALUES ( 4,517 , 222 ,'Mode Name','New App');
INSERT INTO tblReportData VALUES ( 5,517 , 333 ,'Total Size','5000000');
INSERT INTO tblReportData VALUES ( 6,517 , 444 ,'Table Name','Offline Users');
INSERT INTO tblReportData VALUES ( 7,517 , 444 ,'# Rows','100');
INSERT INTO tblReportData VALUES ( 8,517 , 444 ,'Size','500');
INSERT INTO tblReportData VALUES ( 9,517 , 555 ,'URI','C:\File1');
```

**Query**

```
SELECT Row_number() over(order by data_point_group_key) 'Data_id',
       report_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN data_point = 'Table Name' THEN data_point_value END) as 'Table Name',
       MAX(CASE WHEN data_point = '# Rows' THEN data_point_value END), 
       MAX(CASE WHEN data_point = 'Size' THEN data_point_value END) as 'Size',
       MAX(CASE WHEN data_point = 'Mode Name' THEN data_point_value END) as 'Mode Name',
       MAX(CASE WHEN data_point = 'Total Size' THEN data_point_value END)as 'Total Size',
       MAX(CASE WHEN data_point = 'URI' THEN data_point_value END) as 'URI'
FROM tblReportData 
group by report_id,data_point_group_key
```

**[Results]**:

```
| Data_id | report_id |    Table Name | # of Rows |   Size | Mode Name | Total Size |      URI |
|---------|-----------|---------------|-----------|--------|-----------|------------|----------|
|       1 |       517 |    Work_state |         3 |    100 |    (null) |     (null) |   (null) |
|       2 |       517 |        (null) |    (null) | (null) |   New App |     (null) |   (null) |
|       3 |       517 |        (null) |    (null) | (null) |    (null) |    5000000 |   (null) |
|       4 |       517 | Offline Users |       100 |    500 |    (null) |     (null) |   (null) |
|       5 |       517 |        (null) |    (null) | (null) |    (null) |     (null) | C:\File1 |
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3ba79/10)

Comment: Thank you!  I was able to tag on a 
`where report_id = (select max(report_id) from tblReportData)`

To get today's reports!  Thanks again